# locationmanager didchangeauthorizationstatus not called in background

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

It looks like I am not getting notified by the `delegate` method while the app is in background. I do get the `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` once the app goes to foreground. Has anyone else been successful in getting the `authorizationStatus` in background?

BTW, other `delegate` methods work in the background so I know I have set the right properties in `info.plist`.

Comment: What problem are you having? Your app does not _run_ in the background, so why does it matter that you don't get the notification until you're in the foreground? That is the first moment that your app can actually _do_ anything anyway.

Comment: Matt, I am collecting location updates in the background and logging it.  If the user has switched location off, I'd like to log it.

Answer (score 3):

Even though it's in the delegate class didChangeAuthorization is only called when both of the following are true:

- the user changes app location service authorization status
- the app calls requestWhenInUseAuthorization() or requestAlwaysAuthorization()

It is not called from the background in response to user changing the setting in Settings app, changing the setting will not cause iOS to wake your app up. If the user changes the setting then your app will simply stop receiving location updates, it won't know why until the next time the app is in foreground.

Comment: Is there any proof of such behavior in documentation? I have the same observation, but not sure if it is the only way to get didChangeAuthorization to work